# Nologging materialized view

Tags: oracle, materialized-view, dataguard

I need to create a materialized view (MV) with auto refresh every hour. After I create it, a lot of redo logs are generated (10GB per hour). I think the solution is to recreate the MV in NOLOGGING mode.

Are there some problems with my DG database and with a second DG database in read only mode?

Can my RMAN backups restore fail, or do I need only to recreate the MV after a data recovery?

Answer (score 1):

Redo log is crucial in data guard environment. Hence we enable force logging before configuring data guard at the database level. So, no matter whether you use `NOLOGGING` clause or not the operation will be logged and replicated in the standby site.

> When you perform a DML or DDL operation using the NOLOGGING or UNRECOVERABLE clause, the standby database is invalidated and may require substantial DBA administrative activities to repair. You can specify the SQL ALTER DATABASE or SQL ALTER TABLESPACE statement with the FORCE LOGGING clause to override the NOLOGGING setting. However, this statement will not repair an already invalidated database.

[NOLOGGING or Unrecoverable Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/manage_ps.htm#SBYDB00206)

You might be interested in this thread from the asktom site.

[Dataguard and Nologging](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6675683600346422502)